# Create dictionary with a for loop

Tags: python, image, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with Key value pairs which are filled via an for Loop

The dictionary I want to achive

```
[
  { 
    "timestamp": 123123123,
    "image": "image/test1.png"
   },
  {
    "timestamp": 0384030434,
    "image": "image/test2.png"
  }

]
```

My code does not work and I´m new to the datatypes of python.

```
    images_dict = []
    for i in images:
      time = Image.open(i)._getexif()[36867]
      images_dict = {"timestamp": time, "image": i}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `images_dict.append({"timestamp": time, "image": i})`

Comment: In the future instead of saying "my code does not work", you should say what error you are having. i.e. what is printed to the console

Answer (score 1):

First, you seem to be confusing the definition of a list and a dictionary in python. Dictionaries use curly brackets `{}` and lists use regular brackets `[]`. So in your first example, you are describing a list with a single element, which is a dictionary.

As for your code example, you are creating an empty list, and then iterating over `images` which I assume is a list of images, and then redefining the variable `images_dict` to be a dictionary with two `key: value` pairs for every iteration.

It seems like what you want is this:

```
images_dict = []
for image in images:
    time = Image.open(1)._getexif()[36867]
    images_dict.append({'timestamp': time, 'image': image})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Tom McLean worked for me, I´m a little bit confused with the dataypes of python

```
images_dict.append({"timestamp": time, "image": i})
```